# How to do unit testing of Custom View when having only the APK?

Tags: android, testing, android-custom-view, robotium, android-install-apk

I've an apk to be tested using Robotium. In the application I'm going to test there is a custom view(Window) on which there are some text and numeric parameters drawn using ownerDrawn and Paint.  The custom view is a child of the relative layout. Since I'm not able to get the resource id of either the custom view(window) or the parameters drawn on it,I'm finding it hard to test the existance of parameters on that view. Please help me out with a solution on how would I do that.

Thanks

Custom View is as shown here:

[image: CustomView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you are likely to continue to be out of luck. You could get hold of the custome view by casting the view above it in the heirarchy to a view group and getting the child. The custom view though is unlikely to have the information you want. Android and Robotium will not know any details about it other than its view type.

What you can do though is get developers to give you this information via tags. E.g. if it contains the text "hello world" they could also set a tag on that view which would allow you to get the text from it. This sounds like it might not be possible in your situatuion.

Comment: Hi Paul Harris : Thank you so much for your response. That gives me a bit relief. But however I need to get a solution for this. I'm not finding the ways to do it. Your inputs are always welcome.

Comment: If it is completely custom, as in they draw what is displayed rather than built from other view types, you are completely at the mercy of your developers, robotium will have no idea what that view contains by default as it is completely custom. You will need the developers to give you something, tags accesability labels are the obvious ones. You might manage to achieve what you want by getting hold of the activity that is being tests and from that be able to call methods on it to get the information you require.

Comment: Hi, moreover the parameters in the custom view are dynamic.

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same apart from using Robotium?

Comment: Hi Paul Harris,please have a look at the attached image of custom view.

Comment: Nothing will do it out of the box, as i said the only way is get into the activity/view code to see what values the developers set really. There is one other option but i loathe to suggest it, you could do image recognition. There are tools such as sikuli that you can use with an emulator to check that parts of the screen will match to an expected picture.

Comment: Can I do this using UiAutomator?

Comment: Only if the developers have added accessability labels with the information you require.